# How to store values from a function in python?

Tags: python, function, variables

I have a function:

```
def get_val():
    for a in b:
        c = b['values']
        print (c)
```

When I call the function `get_val()`, I get the result which is a long list of values with numbering up to 1000.  `type(c)` is `float`.

Now I want to store this result from the function into a variable e. I tried using `return c` instead of `print(c)`

Return function is not convenient because it will only return a line instead of the whole 1000.

Comment: if you need everything after paste it into a list. lst=[] for a in b: c = b[‘values’]  lst.append(c)...

Comment: If you simply return instead of print it will return in 1st iteration only. Add the value in a list and then after exiting from loop.

Comment: It’s not working

Answer (score 0):

One-liner in Python using [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it):

```
def get_val(b):
    # Do something else
    return [i["values"] for i in b]
```

**Note: I am assuming you mistyped `a['values']` and you meant `i[values]`**

Comment: You mis-typed the correct version of OP's mis-type.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to find a way around it with some help.

outside the function

create an empty list and run it so it's defined.

```
     new_list = []
```

then go back to the function and append c

so you have:

```
    def get_val():
      for a in b:
          c = b['values']
          new_list.append(c)
```